# Adding a border (Fixed3D) to an existing borderless application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an .NET application that always starts itself with its border style to 'None', as it is supposed to be an full-screen application with a fixed resolution.

However, i would like to add the window border (Fixed3D) to this window when the application starts so that I am able to move it around my desktop.

My first idea was to have a tray app running, monitoring event messages, and somehow change the window style when this specific application starts. However, I am not sure if this will work and how to do this.

Anyone that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: you mean you don't have the code for the borderless application? and you want to control it using another application?

Comment: I do have the code for the borderless application. However, i cannot change this code.  This application sets its frmMain.BorderStyle to None.

What i want is to somehow add a border around the frmMain, without touching that code.

My first suggestion is to somehow catch WM_PAINT and force the border style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably look into using the [`SetWindowLongPtr`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/setwindowlongptr.html) function of **user32.dll**.

You'll need to get the window handle associated with the application's main window. This could potentially be done using:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process process in processes) {
    if (process.MainModule.FileName == @"C:\Program Files\App\app.exe") {
        IntPtr handle = process.MainWindowHandle;
        // Call method to change window style here.
        break;
    }
}
```

You can then set the appropriate styles using the `GWL_STYLE` constant (value -16 in decimal) and `SetWindowLongPtr`.

[Changing the Style of the Main Window](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/111011/en-gb) should help you find the styles that you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit a class from a main class in the source code, and change its properties in the appropriate events. hat would be no modification of the source code, though it would be a different application.

Comment: That would indeed be a nice solution.

Unfortunately in my specific situation the Program's Main executes a lot of internal logic, which in turn creates the mainForm. 

Besides, I cannot touch the actual solution and the internal code. I must approach it like i do not have the sources; however i am able to 'see' them.